# Updating while creating table mySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to write update statements inside of create table statements in mySQL?Assume we have two different tables.When I insert something on one table I want to change the value in other table.Is this possible in mySQL

Comment: **write update statements inside of create table statements** why would you like to write an `update` statement inside of `create` statement? you should separate both, since they do not do the same process .

Comment: I am finishing a project and they wanted our create table statements with update statements so I guess I need to write them seperately.Thank you,I was confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

More specification is required. 

If you have 2 tables and you have already created both of them then you need to fire update query on both of the tables.

If you have only 1 table and you are about to create second table then I would recommend you to use data import/export functionality.